# Loop through Firebase "users" collection and return users who are in a "friends" array

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm building a simple Facebook clone with React and Firebase and this is what the users collection looks like:

[image: firebase users collection]

Users can store their friends by their user document ID. I am setting these friends in a friends variable when the user logs in:

```
const [friends, setFriends] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFriends(userInfo[0]?.data.friends);
    })
```

My question is, how can I loop through the users and display only users that are in the friends array? Here is the code I have that isn't working because it's not checking any particular value in the friends array:

```
<Row>
{users.map(user => (
user.id == friends ?
(
<Col>
<div
id={user.id}
key={user.id}
>
<h3
>
{user.data.name}
</h3>
<Link>
<button
>
View Profile
</button>
</Link>
</div>
</Col>
) : null
))}
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"friends" is an array which contains a list of user id. So in this case you compare user.id to an array (friends) and it cannot work.

Instead, you should change the statement to:
`users.map( user => friends.includes(user.id) ? ... : ...)`, so if the user.id in the friends array, it will return what you expect.

By the way, you should add userInto as a dependency to your useEffect, ex:
`useEffect( () => {...},[userInfo])`, so the state will only be updated when the userInfo data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code:

```
users.map ((user,index)=>{
if (friends && friends.includes(user.id)){
//then do what you want on true condition 
})
```